# How to close an work item in Omni Channel with automation?

Tags: omnichannel, agentwork

I am setting up Omni-Channel and I have two picklist fields "Status" and "Department" in a custom object where when certain values are selected it should remove the work item from the user's workload. However, with  [Status Based Capacity Model](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.omnichannel_status_based_capacity.htm&type=5), I can only use one field.

I look into adding the second field by accessing the Agentwork object in a Flow and updating the Status but according to the [SF Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.omni_channel_dev.meta/omni_channel_dev/sforce_api_objects_agentwork.htm):

> While the metadata for AgentWork indicates support for upsert() and update(), these calls aren’t used with AgentWork because none of its fields can be updated.

Is this another way I can set to update the Status of the work to close the work?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a third field, perhaps hidden, with values open/closed, map status-based capacity to it, and then use automation of some form to set the values of it based upon the logic that you want on your multiple fields.